# iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I'm running Debian and I'm trying to use iptables to set some firewall rules but I'm just getting an error:

```
iptables/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported
```

It doesn't matter what kind of rule I'm trying to set, it just gives me the same error. I've tried googling the error without finding anything.

These are the rules that I'm trying to set:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Anyone who has an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Debian 10 is using [iptables over nftables by default](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables). That means a different `iptables` command ([`iptables-nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-nft.8)) is communicating with the kernel nftables API: it actually translates every *iptables* rule into an *nftables* rule, while keeping *xtables* module extension compatibility when a direct native translation doesn't exist for the extension.

Since, somehow, your kernel *nftables* API is not functional (my guess is that it's not a standard Debian 10 kernel and nftables support was not enabled. What is answering `uname -r`?), the command fails. you can still choose to revert to the legacy iptables command which communicates only with the iptables kernel  API, by changing the userland command actually executed, as explained in the previous link:

> ```
> # update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
> # update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
> # update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
> # update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
> ```

You still have to investigate on your non-fuctional *nftables* features. Since switching from iptables to (native) nftables brings great advantages, that would be too bad to not be able to.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me came from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108165/34248): I needed to reboot after a kernel upgrade. The easiest way is of course:

```
# as root
shutdown -r now
```